# Wrong number of child divs are inserted with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

my pen: http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/MYvZKL

Its late here and I am lazy. I can not find the tiny error.

I have 13 child divs, each 6 on a page.

That should give me 2,16666 pages. So I round up to 3 pages.

Therefore I would expect 3 green li-elements with page class.

But there are only 2???

Why?

```
   <ul id='command-pager' class="pagination">         
    </ul>
<div id="current-commands">
  <div class="command">1</div>
  <div class="command">2</div>
  <div class="command">3</div>
  <div class="command">4</div>
  <div class="command">5</div>
  <div class="command">6</div>

  <div class="command">1</div>
  <div class="command">2</div>    
  <div class="command">3</div>
  <div class="command">4</div>
  <div class="command">5</div>  
  <div class="command">6</div>

  <div class="command">1</div> 

</div>

.command{
  background:orange;
  border:1px solid blue;
  width:100px;
}

.page{
  background:green;
}

  $( document ).ready(function(){ 
      commandPager();
  });

function commandPager()
{ 
  var maxCommandsPerPage = 6;
  var totalCommands = $('#current-commands > div').length;
  alert(totalCommands);
  var numOfPages = totalCommands / maxCommandsPerPage;
  var allPages = Math.round(numOfPages)
  for(var i = 1; i <= allPages ; i++)
    {  
      $('#command-pager').append('<li class="page">' + i +'</li>')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var numOfPages = 13 / 6;
//numOfPages == 2.16
//Math.round(2.16) == 2; // (its below 2.5 so it rounds to 2)
```

You want to use Math.ceil() instead of Math.round().

```
//Math.ceil(2.16) == 3;
```